# Prevent writing back for Neo4j algo

Tags: neo4j, permissions, graph-algorithm

I work with a Neo4j database where I only have read permission.

I'm trying to run some of the algo algorithms. E.g. a community detection algo.scc.

According to the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-algorithms/current/labs-algorithms/strongly-connected-components/) algo.scc has a parameter `write` which

> Specifies if the result should be written back as a node property.

However when I run it with `write` set to `false`

```
CALL algo.scc('Employee','MANAGES', {write:false})
YIELD loadMillis, computeMillis, writeMillis, setCount, maxSetSize, minSetSize;
```

I get the following error:

`Neo.ClientError.Security.Forbidden: Write operations are not allowed for user 'dm00221' with roles [reader].`

I couldn't find any examples in documentation with `{write:false}` option. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if it helps.

```
CALL algo.scc.stream('Employee', 'MANAGES', {concurrency:4})
YIELD nodeId, partition
```